# Computer Vision techniques to find the slope of the buildings with respect to the ground?

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision

I want to find the slope of the building with respect to the ground which means that I need to find how tilted is the building with respect to the ground through computer vision or any other techniques?

Comment: Given [perspective distortion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_distortion_(photography)), this sounds *difficult*.

Comment: Your question is by far too general and vague. I don't even grasp what you call "the tilting of a building wrt to the ground". (I would expect some kind of direction wrt to vertical). A priori you need to resort to 3D reconstruction techniques, but it is too hard to tell. Spend some time explaining your problem.

Comment: So the problem is that, I want to know that how much tilted the buikding is from its foundation